# Get pushed element to mongoose array in the callback function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The schema of the document is given below:

```
author: String,
    
    title: String, 
    comments:[
        {
            commentAuthor: String,
            comment: String,
            dateOfComment: String
        }
    ]
```

I am trying to push a new comment to the `comments` array as given below:

```
SocialPost.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.id},{$push:{comments: req.body}}, function(err, result){
        if(err) res.send(err);
        else res.json(result);
    })
```

The comment is being pushed successfully but what I want is that the callback function should return the pushed comment along with the mongoose unique ObjectId so that I can return the comment to the front-end. But the `result` contains the entire document, which I don't need.

Please help me to find how can I achieve this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
let comment = result.comments[result.commetns.length - 1];
res.json(comment);
```

you will have access to the comment and its id in the comment object

Comment: Sorry, but I don't need the id of he post but the id of the pushed comment. result._id will send the post id.